# Deleting de-activated stateful actors

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I've learned that stateful actors are de-activated after being idle for a period of time (60 mins by default). This will free RAM (and CPU) from the nodes that were hosting those actors. However, their state will remain in the cluster in case they need to be re-activated.

I'm wondering if it is possible to somehow enumerate de-activated actors (that have persisted state) in order to permanently delete some of them based on some custom criteria.

The goal of this would be to free disk space in the cluster, knowing that some actors won't ever be activated again (and if they would, they would act just as if they're brand new).

As a side benefit, if it is indeed possible to get a list of "once activated but possibly de-activated" actors, then we would not have to maintain such a list manually.

Comment: If expired actors' state are not important you might want to use stateless actors instead, with private variables.

Comment: In my scenario, it's crucial that actor's state is persistent and replicated. Although, over time some actor's state will no longer serve any purpose and will never be needed again. I'd like to be able to clean up that state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible today but it is a common ask and something that we are actively working on.

**UPDATE - 2016-04-04**

This feature was added in the 1.5.175 SDK.

Comment: Ok. Can I count on this feature being present in the near future (< 6 months or so)? If so we could continue with our design and add this feature later on.

Comment: No guarantees but I would be surprised if this is not available in that time frame.

Comment: This feature is now available. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2016/02/23/service-fabric-sdk-v1-5-175-and-the-adoption-of-virtual-machine-scale-sets/